# I need to create more faces( but ctrl+r in edit mode isnt working), how do i do it alternatively?

Tags: modeling

I downloaded a model from a website and got permission to use it for non profit/open source projects.

Problem is that I cant use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to divide the faces into smaller multiple faces.

If I use <kbd>W</kbd>> *Subdivide* I get more or less the result I need (far from perfect but it can/could work), but the faces have triangles inside them, causing too many faces that wouldnt crash realistically. Is there an alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or a way to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> working again and remove triangles inside the faces (whithout deleting the faces) where I dont need them? If I remove them manually using <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>W</kbd>> *Subdivide* wont create vertical edges I need.

I cant use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to do it, any alternative way to do it? If I use knife to do it (easiest way) the edges I get are not vertical.

If I use <kbd>W</kbd>> *Subdivide* I get too many diagonal edges from my current diagonal edges (most of which I dont need, but if I remove them then <kbd>W</kbd>> *Subdivide* does nothing.

Any ideas how to fix it?

This is what I want:

[image: Top view Pink = edges I need to create]
[image]

This is what it should look like(12+ or so little square faces per body panel):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sadly I am too much of a amateur to help other blender users(started using a month or so ago) and hence its hard for me to get 10 reputation to post all the pics and info I need on my main post......

Comment: This is a copy of my project file in .zip: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6vRqq08Rx2Ja2pIRFNpTEZyZWM and this is those little square faces I need to create on my project model, every bodypanel has 12+ of those: https://wiki.beamng.com/images/thumb/9/9b/01_ss-2013-08-11-at-12.34.12.jpg/800px-01_ss-2013-08-11-at-12.34.12.jpg

Comment: The knife tool will make straight cuts.  You must be in Orthographic Perspective and in something like [Top, Front, Right] View.  Once you begin the Knife Tool, press "C" to constrain it to 90 degrees.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3692" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3692/)

Comment: You should first understand why CTL+R does not work. CTL+R is used to add and edge loop. Blender can create edge loop only on quads ('squares'). So with Triangles CTL+R does not work.

Comment: You can only use Ctrl + R on quads. Not on tris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want the Knife tool (the <kbd>K</kbd> tool in edit mode).  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html .  It lets you divide faces along a line you choose.

[image: knife tool in action]

If you decide those vertices aren't in the exact right place you can use Vertex Slide <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to slide them into the right place.

If that model's triangulation is a problem and you want to turn them back into quads, consider the Dissolve Edges operator (in the <kbd>X</kbd> menu.

Comment: Currently trying it out! seems to work for now!

Comment: <kbd> Formatting represents keys on your keyboard. You do not have a key on your keyboard which says 'shift-v' (nor do you have lowercase letters). That, and trying to conform your formatting to the way kbd formatting is shown on the rest of the site was why I edited your answer. Unless it was accidental, I don't understand why you have undone that edit.

Comment: I was in the middle of adding a paragraph about Dissolve Edges and it must have stomped on your edit.

Comment: Evidently there are keyboards with lowercase letters: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chromebook-central/PNqWLYEgpHQ/ySJmbjfOBQAJ  and it is not universally popular.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You guys have been really useful, especially you and Stéphane Monté(him whit the disolve angle trick)!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use bisect.Select the faces that you want to be divided then select bisect from the toolbar.[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the knife tool to have a perfectly straigth cut what you should do:

Select all the triangles in the hood and X -> Select dissolve, set the angle to 0.2°. You should end up with that :

[image: After limited dissolve]

Then you need to create extra vertices the border edges of the hood, as much as cut that you need. Select the edges and subdivide them.

[image: Subdivide the edges]

Then use the knife tool to cut the faces by relying on the newly created verticies.

[image: Cut the faces]

And Voila! Much better topo and not shading problem.

[image]